# How do I read a local file in JavaScript using relative addressing

Tags: javascript, json, file, widget

I am writing a widget (discord) to upload to a website (so I can't use absolute as the location of the config file will change when I upload it) and I made a configuration file under the same directory. Is there a way to access this config file so my widget can read it wherever it is placed.

---

**JavaScript Code:**

```js
function readTextFile(file, callback) {
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.overrideMimeType("application/json");
    rawFile.open("GET", file, true);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (rawFile.readyState === 4 && rawFile.status == "200") {
            callback(rawFile.responseText);
        }
    }
    rawFile.send(null);
}

var json_url;

readTextFile("config.json", function(text){ //read the configuration file (config.json)
    var config = JSON.parse(text);
    json_url = "https://discordapp.com/api/guilds/" + config.server_id + "/widget.json";
    console.log(config.server_id); //debug line
    
});
```

---

**JSON:**

```
{
    "server_id" : "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "invite_link" : "https://discord.gg/XXXXXXX"
}
```

Comment: It won't work? Any error or something.

Comment: Here's the error message, from the console

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token / in JSON at position 40`
    `at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)`
    `at widget.js:24`
    `at XMLHttpRequest.rawFile.onreadystatechange (widget.js:15)`
`(anonymous) @ widget.js:24`
`rawFile.onreadystatechange @ widget.js:15`
`XMLHttpRequest.send (async)`
`readTextFile @ widget.js:18`
`(anonymous) @ widget.js:23`
`widget.js:18 
`GET http://127.0.0.1:56306/widget/undefined 404 (Not Found)`